# JSON object getting damaged when using chrome.storage.local.set

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

When retrieving a complex JSON object from chrome.storage.local the object is breaking.

> mock.json

```
{
"ThingOne" : [
    "a", 
    "b"
],
"ThineTwo" : [
    "a", 
    "b"
],
"People" : {
    "FamilyOne" : {
        "AgeOne" : "3",
        "AgeTwo" : "8"
    }
},
"Hats" : ["blue", "red", "green"]
```

}

and I am fetching this file (correctly) using

```
    fetch('./mock.json').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        //data == the whole json file

        var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
        chrome.storage.local.set({'StoredJson': data2});

        //here this is the result of this code
        //console.log(data2.ThingOne[0]);
        //outputs => "a"

    
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
    });
    
    waitfunction();
    chrome.storage.local.get('StoredJson', function(result) {
        console.log("from get ------"); //outputs below
        console.log(result); //{Data: ""{\"ThingOneOne\":[\"a\",\"b\"],\...
        console.log(typeof result); //object
        console.log(typeof result.ThingOne);//undefined
        //https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUmkq.jpg
    });
```

Why is it working when I fetch the object but not when I retrieve it. I have tried storing it after JSON.stringifying it. And I have tried to use it after JSON.parsing it which returns

> VM6:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()

indicating that it is already a JS object.
I have tried using dot notation and bracket notaion it doesn't work. When I store it in the chrome console as var data = {//json here} it works. But not live. [StackOverflow: Save json to chrome storage / local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951170/save-json-to-chrome-storage-local-storage) hasn't helped me. [Picture of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUmkq.jpg)

Comment: You don't need to stringify an object before storing it in `chrome.storage`. You can do this directly: `chrome.storage.local.set({'StoredJson': data})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code.

1. There's no need for JSON.stringify. Just store the data directly.
2. Both `fetch` and `chrome.storage` are asynchronous so your `chrome.storage.local.get` will run before the data is set and it won't see the correct data.
3. `waitfunction();` won't wait for anything, it won't influence asynchronous code before it or afterwards.
4. `chrome.storage.local.get('StoredJson', callback)` reads the data into an object property named `StoredJson` i.e. you can read the value as `result.StoredJson`.

Overall, a proper modern solution is to switch to `async/await`:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await (await fetch('./mock.json')).json();
    console.log('Fetched', data);
    await writeStorage({StoredJson: data});
    const {StoredJson} = await readStorage('StoredJson');
    console.log('Stored', StoredJson);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();

function readStorage(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, resolve);
  });
}

function writeStorage(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.local.set(data, resolve);
  });
}
```

Comment: TL;DR #4 was the main issue.    Thank you for your response. 1. I have tried every combination of JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, and I was trying to convey that but I didn't, that's my fault. 2. I understand they are asynchronous. I have a messy settimeout system right now in my real code that works, I was trying to simplify that for the problem. 3. assuming the wait function works shouldn't that prevent the code from running after it?. 4. Yes I was screwing that up, I have fixed that but now as I read the object it is of typeof string. JSON.parse fixed it. (2 day frustrating bug, sincerely ty